GCC error message does not match source code
I'm compiling linux kernel 6.2.16 using gcc. I run compilation using command make V=1, and I got these really weird errors:
In file included from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:26,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from ./include/linux/sched/task_stack.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/elfcore.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/crash_core.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/kexec.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/crash_dump.h:5,
                 from arch/x86/kernel/e820.c:12:
./include/linux/irqflags.h:180:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive #tefine; did you mean #define?
  180 | #define raw_local_irq_restore(flags)                    \
      |  ^~~~~~
      |  define
./arch/x86/include/asm/special_insns.h: In function ‘native_load_gs_index’:
./include/linux/irqflags.h:178:25: error: implicit declaration of function ‘arch_local_irq_sqve’; did you mean ‘arch_local_irq_save’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  178 |                 flags = arch_local_irq_save();          \
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:244:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_irq_save’
  244 | #define local_irq_save(flags)   do { raw_local_irq_save(flags); } while (0)
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/x86/include/asm/special_insns.h:129:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘local_irq_save’
  129 |         local_irq_save(flags);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:245:39: error: implicit declaration of function ‘raw_local_irq_restore’; did you mean ‘arch_local_irq_restore’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  245 | #define local_irq_restore(flags) do { raw_local_irq_restore(flags); } while (0)
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/x86/include/asm/special_insns.h:131:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘local_irq_restore’
  131 |         local_irq_restore(flags);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:60,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:78,
                 from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:27,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from ./include/linux/sched/task_stack.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/elfcore.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/crash_core.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/kexec.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/crash_dump.h:5,
                 from arch/x86/kernel/e820.c:12:
./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h: At top level:
./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:156:2: error: invalid preprocessing directive #ivndef; did you mean #ifndef?
  156 | #ifndef __ASSEMBLY__
      |  ^~~~~~
      |  ifndef
./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:167:7: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘inline’
  167 | static inline int arch_within_stack_frames(const void * const stack,
      |       ^
      |       ;
./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:237:2: error: #endif without #if
  237 | #endif /* _ASM_X86_THREAD_INFO_H */
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:26,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from ./include/linux/sched/task_stack.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/elfcore.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/crash_core.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/kexec.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/crash_dump.h:5,
                 from arch/x86/kernel/e820.c:12:
./include/linux/rcupdate.h: In function ‘rcu_read_lock_sched_held’:
./include/linux/irqflags.h:189:25: error: ‘arch_local_save_flags8’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘arch_local_save_flags’?
  189 |                 flags = arch_local_save_flags();        \
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:261:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_save_flags’
  261 |                 raw_local_save_flags(_flags);           \
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/preempt.h:215:51: note: in expansion of macro ‘irqs_disabled’
  215 | #define preemptible()   (preempt_count() == 0 && !irqs_disabled())
      |                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/rcupdate.h:358:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘preemptible’
  358 |         return !preemptible();
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:189:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  189 |                 flags = arch_local_save_flags();        \
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:261:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_save_flags’
  261 |                 raw_local_save_flags(_flags);           \
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/preempt.h:215:51: note: in expansion of macro ‘irqs_disabled’
  215 | #define preemptible()   (preempt_count() == 0 && !irqs_disabled())
      |                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/rcupdate.h:358:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘preemptible’
  358 |         return !preemptible();
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:189:47: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
  189 |                 flags = arch_local_save_flags();        \
      |                                               ^
./include/linux/irqflags.h:261:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_save_flags’
  261 |                 raw_local_save_flags(_flags);           \
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/preempt.h:215:51: note: in expansion of macro ‘irqs_disabled’
  215 | #define preemptible()   (preempt_count() == 0 && !irqs_disabled())
      |                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/rcupdate.h:358:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘preemptible’
  358 |         return !preemptible();
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:189:47: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
  189 |                 flags = arch_local_save_flags();        \
      |                                               ^
./include/linux/irqflags.h:261:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_save_flags’
  261 |                 raw_local_save_flags(_flags);           \
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/preempt.h:215:51: note: in expansion of macro ‘irqs_disabled’
  215 | #define preemptible()   (preempt_count() == 0 && !irqs_disabled())
      |                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/rcupdate.h:358:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘preemptible’
  358 |         return !preemptible();
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/rcupdate.h: In function ‘rcu_read_lock_any_held’:
./include/linux/irqflags.h:189:25: error: ‘arch_local_save_flags8’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘arch_local_save_flags’?
  189 |                 flags = arch_local_save_flags();        \
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:261:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_save_flags’
  261 |                 raw_local_save_flags(_flags);           \
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/preempt.h:215:51: note: in expansion of macro ‘irqs_disabled’
  215 | #define preemptible()   (preempt_count() == 0 && !irqs_disabled())
      |                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/rcupdate.h:363:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘preemptible’
  363 |         return !preemptible();
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:189:47: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
  189 |                 flags = arch_local_save_flags();        \
      |                                               ^
./include/linux/irqflags.h:261:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_save_flags’
  261 |                 raw_local_save_flags(_flags);           \
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/preempt.h:215:51: note: in expansion of macro ‘irqs_disabled’
  215 | #define preemptible()   (preempt_count() == 0 && !irqs_disabled())
      |                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/rcupdate.h:363:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘preemptible’
  363 |         return !preemptible();
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:189:47: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
  189 |                 flags = arch_local_save_flags();        \
      |                                               ^
./include/linux/irqflags.h:261:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_save_flags’
  261 |                 raw_local_save_flags(_flags);           \
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/preempt.h:215:51: note: in expansion of macro ‘irqs_disabled’
  215 | #define preemptible()   (preempt_count() == 0 && !irqs_disabled())
      |                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/rcupdate.h:363:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘preemptible’
  363 |         return !preemptible();
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:26,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from ./include/linux/sched/task_stack.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/elfcore.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/crash_core.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/kexec.h:18,
                 from ./include/linux/crash_dump.h:5,
                 from arch/x86/kernel/e820.c:12:
./include/acpi/platform/aclinuxex.h: In function ‘acpi_os_allocate’:
./include/linux/irqflags.h:189:25: error: ‘arch_local_save_flags8’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘arch_local_save_flags’?
  189 |                 flags = arch_local_save_flags();        \
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:261:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_save_flags’
  261 |                 raw_local_save_flags(_flags);           \
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/acpi/platform/aclinuxex.h:52:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘irqs_disabled’
   52 |         return kmalloc(size, irqs_disabled()? GFP_ATOMIC : GFP_KERNEL);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:189:47: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
  189 |                 flags = arch_local_save_flags();        \
      |                                               ^
./include/linux/irqflags.h:261:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_save_flags’
  261 |                 raw_local_save_flags(_flags);           \
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/acpi/platform/aclinuxex.h:52:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘irqs_disabled’
   52 |         return kmalloc(size, irqs_disabled()? GFP_ATOMIC : GFP_KERNEL);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:189:47: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
  189 |                 flags = arch_local_save_flags();        \
      |                                               ^
./include/linux/irqflags.h:261:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_save_flags’
  261 |                 raw_local_save_flags(_flags);           \
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/acpi/platform/aclinuxex.h:52:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘irqs_disabled’
   52 |         return kmalloc(size, irqs_disabled()? GFP_ATOMIC : GFP_KERNEL);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/acpi/platform/aclinuxex.h: In function ‘acpi_os_allocate_zeroed’:
./include/linux/irqflags.h:189:25: error: ‘arch_local_save_flags8’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘arch_local_save_flags’?
  189 |                 flags = arch_local_save_flags();        \
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:261:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_save_flags’
  261 |                 raw_local_save_flags(_flags);           \
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/acpi/platform/aclinuxex.h:57:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘irqs_disabled’
   57 |         return kzalloc(size, irqs_disabled()? GFP_ATOMIC : GFP_KERNEL);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:189:47: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
  189 |                 flags = arch_local_save_flags();        \
      |                                               ^
./include/linux/irqflags.h:261:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_save_flags’
  261 |                 raw_local_save_flags(_flags);           \
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/acpi/platform/aclinuxex.h:57:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘irqs_disabled’
   57 |         return kzalloc(size, irqs_disabled()? GFP_ATOMIC : GFP_KERNEL);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:189:47: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
  189 |                 flags = arch_local_save_flags();        \
      |                                               ^
./include/linux/irqflags.h:261:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_save_flags’
  261 |                 raw_local_save_flags(_flags);           \
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/acpi/platform/aclinuxex.h:57:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘irqs_disabled’
   57 |         return kzalloc(size, irqs_disabled()? GFP_ATOMIC : GFP_KERNEL);
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/acpi/platform/aclinuxex.h: In function ‘acpi_os_acquire_object’:
./include/linux/irqflags.h:189:25: error: ‘arch_local_save_flags8’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘arch_local_save_flags’?
  189 |                 flags = arch_local_save_flags();        \
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:261:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_save_flags’
  261 |                 raw_local_save_flags(_flags);           \
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/acpi/platform/aclinuxex.h:68:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘irqs_disabled’
   68 |                                  irqs_disabled()? GFP_ATOMIC : GFP_KERNEL);
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:189:47: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
  189 |                 flags = arch_local_save_flags();        \
      |                                               ^
./include/linux/irqflags.h:261:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_save_flags’
  261 |                 raw_local_save_flags(_flags);           \
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/acpi/platform/aclinuxex.h:68:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘irqs_disabled’
   68 |                                  irqs_disabled()? GFP_ATOMIC : GFP_KERNEL);
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/irqflags.h:189:47: error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
  189 |                 flags = arch_local_save_flags();        \
      |                                               ^
./include/linux/irqflags.h:261:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_local_save_flags’
  261 |                 raw_local_save_flags(_flags);           \
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/acpi/platform/aclinuxex.h:68:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘irqs_disabled’
   68 |                                  irqs_disabled()? GFP_ATOMIC : GFP_KERNEL);
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:252: arch/x86/kernel/e820.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:504: arch/x86/kernel] Error 2
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:504: arch/x86] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:2021: .] Error 2

As everyone can see, the error given by gcc does not match the source code, for example, it says #define is #tefine.
I tried to compile the same code on a remote server, and it finished nice. I only get this kind of error on my own computer. What might happened and what should I do? Does it relate to my hardware?
P.S. My computer is using r5-2600x as cpu, 8G*2 memory. GCC version 11.4.0. System Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (not Ubuntu pro). Kernel 5.15.0-130-generic.

Have you tried reinstalling the compiler? I suspect something has gotten corrupted.

Thanks for @n. m. could be an AI and @Charles Duffy, who gave me answer at the staging ground. This might be caused by memory damange. I used memtest86 to check my memory and got 10000 errors(which reached the upper limit of memtest86). Since I don't have spare memory to replace the old ones, it seems that this is the most possible answer.
